# How do I install Surfshark VPN?

Tags: apt

I have followed all the directions from the surfshark page but it will not install on my PC. I keep getting this message in the command prompt. I am new to Ubuntu.

```
akash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$ sudo apt install curl
https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh 
[sudo] password for akash: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
bash: https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh: No such file or directory
akash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libaom3:amd64 (3.3.0-1) ...
Setting up libmng2:amd64 (2.0.3+dfsg-3) ...
Setting up libdouble-conversion3:amd64 (3.1.7-4) ...
Setting up libxcb-xinput0:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libigdgmm12:amd64 (22.1.2+ds1-1) ...
Setting up fonts-open-sans (1.11-2) ...
Setting up libpcre2-16-0:amd64 (10.39-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libxcb-xinerama0:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libva2:amd64 (2.14.0-1) ...
Setting up intel-media-va-driver:amd64 (22.3.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libaacs0:amd64 (0.11.1-1) ...
Setting up libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libva-drm2:amd64 (2.14.0-1) ...
Setting up ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 (2.2.14-3) ...
Setting up libvdpau1:amd64 (1.4-3build2) ...
Setting up libqt5dbus5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libmd4c0:amd64 (0.4.8-1) ...
Setting up libmfx1:amd64 (22.3.0-1) ...
Setting up libva-x11-2:amd64 (2.14.0-1) ...
Setting up kwayland-data (4:5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libqt5network5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libavutil56:amd64 (7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libqt5gui5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libqt5widgets5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up qt5-image-formats-plugins:amd64 (5.15.3-1) ...
Setting up libqt5svg5:amd64 (5.15.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
akash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$ sudo apt install curl
https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-open-sans intel-media-va-driver kwayland-data libaacs0 libaom3 libavutil56 libcodec2-1.0 libdouble-conversion3 libigdgmm12 libmd4c0 libmfx1 libmng2
  libpcre2-16-0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5svg5 libqt5widgets5 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0
  qt5-image-formats-plugins systemd-hwe-hwdb
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcodec2-1.0 libcurl4
The following NEW packages will be installed
  curl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcodec2-1.0 libcurl4
2 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 278 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 193 kB/8,918 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7 [193 kB]
Fetched 193 kB in 0s (2,469 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 198418 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcodec2-1.0_1.0.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcodec2-1.0:amd64 (1.0.1-3) over (1.0.1-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libcurl4_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7) over (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7) ...
Setting up libcodec2-1.0:amd64 (1.0.1-3) ...
Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7) ...
Setting up curl (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
bash: https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh: No such file or directory
akash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$ cat surfshark-install.sh 
cat: surfshark-install.sh: No such file or directory
akash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$ sh surfshark-install.sh 
sh: 0: cannot open surfshark-install.sh: No such file
akash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$ curl -f https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh 
#!/bin/sh
PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin"
_ARCHS=$(dpkg --print-architecture && dpkg --print-foreign-architectures)

if ! echo "$_ARCHS" | grep amd64 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Unsupported architecture. $( echo "$_ARCHS" | tr '\n' ' ')"
    exit 1
fi

SUDO="sudo"
if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
    SUDO=
fi
sudo -k

echo "This script requires superuser access to install apt package."

set -ex

$SUDO apt-get remove -y surfshark surfshark-release || true

$SUDO tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/surfshark.asc << PGP_KEY
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=bVHI
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
PGP_KEY
echo "deb https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch main" | $SUDO tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/surfshark.list
$SUDO apt-get update
$SUDO apt-get install -y surfshark

set +x

echo ""
echo "Surfshark was successfully installed."
echo ""
### END OF SCRIPTakash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$ cat surfshark-install.sh 
cat: surfshark-install.sh: No such file or directory
akash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$ sh surfshark-install.sh 
sh: 0: cannot open surfshark-install.sh: No such file
akash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$ cat surfshark-install.sh 
cat: surfshark-install.sh: No such file or directory
akash@akash-Aspire-TC-280:~$
```

Comment: please remove the commands that are not related to the problem. Now it is a wall of text.  
Plus there is a command using SUDO. sudo needs to be small case. Might be the problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind It looks like `curl` dumps the content of the `debian-install.sh` on stdout by default. `SUDO` is an environmental variable in the script being dumped on the screen.

Comment: If you think the answer is correct, please accept it by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't use Surfshark VPN. Without reading the installation instructions Surfshark provided to you, it is hard to know exactly what you are doing incorrectly. However, based on the output you have provided, this is how you may want to proceed next.

## Get the installation script

Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the command (copy from here and paste):

```
curl -O https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh
```

Note the option `-O` that is a minus sign followed by the capital letter O. This option is needed for the command `curl` to save the file it will download. Without that option `curl` will just dump the content of the file on the screen.

**Note:** Surfshark's web page asks you to use the option `-f`. This is the wrong option for saving the file.

**Alternately** you could use the command:

```
wget https://downloads.surfshark.com/linux/debian-install.sh
```

`wget` saves the files it downloads by default.

Now if you enter the commands:

```
ls -l debian-install.sh
```

Note the option `-l, that is a small letter EL.

If the file exists you will see something like:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 akash akash 3269 Feb  7 17:04 debian-install.sh
```

This tells you the file is owned by `akash` and belongs to a group by the same name. You and anyone who belongs to the group called `akash` can read and write to this file.

## Make the script executable

In Ubuntu a script is just a text file until you make it executable. The following command will make the file executable by anyone:

```
chmod +x debian-install.sh
```

Now if you use the `ls -l debian-install.sh` command again you will see the output

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 akash akash 3269 Feb  7 17:04 debian-install.sh
```

Now you are ready to run the installation script.

## Run the installation script

By reading the script I know that the script can be run as an administrator. In Ubuntu we do this with the `sudo prefix`. Enter the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo ./debian-install.sh
```

Note the `./` before the file name. Those two are required. There are no spaces after the `./`.

You can also run the command `./debian-install.sh` without sudo. The script adds `sudo` where required if you don't use it. If all goes well the script will run and the program called `surfshark` will be installed in your computer.

Hope this helps